# Is it possible to use a forgot password url filter?

Tags: functions, filters, login, urls, password

i recently found that a login url filter is available but i can't find a solution for the forgot password as well,

for the login url i use this:

```
function custom_login_url($login_url) {
    return ''.get_option('siteurl'). '/login';
}
add_filter('login_url','custom_login_url');
```

is it possible to do the same for the forgot password?

thanks a lot,
Philip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's also possible for the password, by running a filter on `lostpassword_url`, which is basically the password equivalent of the login url..

## Example

Basically the same as before, just changed the function and hook names.

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'custom_lostpass_url' );

function custom_lostpass_url( $lostpassword_url ) {
    return get_option('siteurl'). '/lostpass';
}
```