# Custom Register Link on Backend Form

Tags: customization, front-end, filters, user-registration

I want a similar solution like this one for my login form on the backend of my WordPress installation: [Forgot Password URL Filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5987/is-it-possible-to-use-a-forgot-password-url-filter)

What I want to do instead of returning a custom forgot password url, I want to return a custom register link (all of this is on the login form at `/wp-login.php`).  Basically I'm trying to white label WordPress completely, and I've got front end forms for creating and editing posts, registering, logging in, profile editing, and post management all in the front end.  However, when someone attempts to login and that attempt is failed, they're redirected to `/wp-login.php`.

Ideally I could throw an error on my site and have it redirect to my front-end login page (is there a filter for that?), but worse case-scenario, I've rebranded my backend form so wordpress doesn't look like an issue (aside from the url being `http://www.site.com/wp-login.php`, but that's not a huge deal)  What I want to know is if there's a filter so I can return a custom register link on the backend, and if possible even a custom login link back there too.

I've learned that there is a lostpassword_url filter, but as far as I know there isn't a register_url filter that I can use to change that.

Any help?

**UPDATE**

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-login.php#L418

This is what I want to hook into with a filter to change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that the registration link is generated on `general-template.php` in `wp-includes`. Look at the function `wp_register`. Here you have a filter called `register` which you can use to filter the `wp-login.php` out.

```
/**
 * Display the Registration or Admin link.
 *
 * Display a link which allows the user to navigate to the registration page if
 * not logged in and registration is enabled or to the dashboard if logged in.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 * @uses apply_filters() Calls 'register' hook on register / admin link content.
 *
 * @param string $before Text to output before the link (defaults to <li>).
 * @param string $after Text to output after the link (defaults to </li>).
 * @param boolean $echo Default to echo and not return the link.
 */
function wp_register( $before = '<li>', $after = '</li>', $echo = true ) {

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if ( get_option('users_can_register') )
            $link = $before . '<a href="' . site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login') . '">' . __('Register') . '</a>' . $after;
        else
            $link = '';
    } else {
        $link = $before . '<a href="' . admin_url() . '">' . __('Site Admin') . '</a>' . $after;
    }

    if ( $echo )
        echo apply_filters('register', $link);
    else
        return apply_filters('register', $link);
}
```

### EDIT

```
add_filter('register', 'wpse28495_wpRegister');
function wpse28495_wpRegister($link) {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $link = '<a href="' . site_url('my-login.php') . '">' . __('Register') . '</a>';
    }

    return $link;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how `add_filter()` works.  How would I apply this to change a link?  Would I add an filter that calls a modified version of this function?

Comment: @Josh I've added a working example. The filter will change the default register URL from `wp-login.php?action=register` to `my-login.php`.

Comment: I've added this to my functions file, but it doesn't change the link at all. :/

Comment: After looking at the backend more, it seems like this is the wrong function, like something that's added to the 'Meta' widget.  In the backend, the HTML just involves a `<p>` and the registration link.  Hmm.

Comment: The filter is for the function `wp_register()` which is used by WordPress in his widgets/themes. If you have another non-standard widget, you have to look at the sourcecode of these for a modification.

Comment: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-login.php#L418  That's the section of code that I want to modify, but I want to be able to do it without modifying the source code.  If I have to for now I will, but it would be great if I could with a filter or action.

Comment: @Josh Unfortunately `wp-login.php` doesn't have a filter for that nor does it uses the builtin functions to authenticate the user. Another way for whitelabeling the login/registration process is to use a complete different page. Instead of `wp-login.php` you could create a `login.php` and authenticate the user on your own with `wp_signon()`. Same for registration with `wp_register()`. This would also require some additional rewrite rules for `hostname.tld/login` and `hostname.tld/register`.

Comment: thanks for replying and letting me know. Creating my own `login.php` seems like something that would work in the future of the project I'm working on.  However, for now I've decided to just alter the WordPress Core.  The only downside for me is that it will have to be edited for every upgrade of WordPress :/  Thanks for all your insight and help!