# Change WP-LOGIN and WP-SIGNUP for any request

Tags: multisite, wp-signup

I want to rename `wp-login.php` and `wp-signup.php` for any request

I tried this

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /wp-login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^signup$ /wp-signup.php [L]
```

but when someone insert a wrong password his redirected from `/login/` to `/wp-login.php`
and in the Second page of registration in Multisite is redirect from `/signup/` to 
`/wp-signup.php`

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5987/is-it-possible-to-use-a-forgot-password-url-filter .  You can't just add a rule to the `.htaccess` file -- you need to filter the URL in WordPress.

Comment: thanks, I solved the problem for "lost password" but when i insert a wrong password I continue to be redirected to /wp-login.php

Comment: Not sure if a Plugin is an option for you, but I've had a lot of success with [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/).

Comment: thanks baut This Plugin didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the Login URL:

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'wpse100354_my_login_url' );
function wpse100354_my_login_url( $login_url ){
    return site_url( '/your-login-url' );
}
```

**Caveat:** I haven't tested this.

### References

#### Codex

[`wp_login_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url)

#### Source code

Adam Brown's reference for [`login_url` filter](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/login_url?version=3.5&file=wp-includes/general-template.php)
Trac page for [`wp-includes/general-template.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php)

Comment: thanks for the help, but I continue to be redirected to /wp-login.php .....nothing has changed :(

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to your question, please?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking.  When I said *add the relevant code to your question*, I meant please add the code that you're using to your question.  (Not my filter -- the code that you had already written, or found, in an effort to solve your problem.)

Comment: I too have misunderstood what you were asking. I added the code but it didn't work ...thanks anyway ...

Comment: WordPress already adds /login and /admin permalinks out of the box, you should not be adding more rewrite rules via htaccess

Comment: yes, the link domain.com/login/ works fine but if i insert a wrong password redirects me from /login/ to /wp-login.php how can I prevent this?